# Different classes with same methods with different parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have three classes: `ToBeMum`, `NewMum`, and `ExperiencedMums`. These classes have different methods which do the same things however they differ in parameters. How can I restructure the code to avoid copy/paste in all the three classes? For example:

NewMum:

```
public List<Question> GetMotherActualDayCareAge()
        {

            List<QuestionInfo> mumsHabits;
            var answers = Answers.GetAnswers;

            string answerValue = string.Empty;

            var oneA = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q49d"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

            var oneB = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q65d"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

            var temp = oneA.Union(oneB).ToList();

            mumsHabits = temp.Intersect(mothers, new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();

            return mumsHabits;
        }
```

ExperiencedMum

```
public List<QuestionInfo> GetMotherActualDayCareAge()
        {
            List<QuestionInfo> mumsHabits;

            var answers = Answers.GetAnswers;

            string answerValue = string.Empty;

            var oneA = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q49c"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

            var oneB = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q65c"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

            var temp = oneA.Union(oneB).ToList();

            mumsHabits = temp.Intersect(mothers, new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();

            return mumsHabits;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna be very simple. You can write a common method with this same concept in a separate class.

For ex, create a class called Helper.cs which should contains the following method

```
public List<QuestionInfo> GetMotherActualDayCareAge(string var1, string var2)
    {
        List<QuestionInfo> mumsHabits;

        var answers = Answers.GetAnswers;

        string answerValue = string.Empty;

        var oneA = from a in answers
                   where a.Questionid == var1
                   select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

        var oneB = from a in answers
                   where a.Questionid == var2
                   select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

        var temp = oneA.Union(oneB).ToList();

        mumsHabits = temp.Intersect(mothers, new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();

        return mumsHabits;
    }
```

Now just call this method wherever needed. In your case, you can call this method from ToBeMum.cs, NewMum.cs, and ExperiencedMums.cs.

For ex, In NewMum.cs, you can just call like this.

```
List<QuestionInfo> quesList = GetMotherActualDayCareAge("Q49d", "Q65d");
```

In ExperiencedMum.cs, you can call like this.

```
List<QuestionInfo> quesList = GetMotherActualDayCareAge("Q49c", "Q65c");
```

So now this becomes dynamic, where only one method is written and the method is called multiple times without copy/paste.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'll use the above suggestions. Could you please suggest more in lines of abstract class and interface. like Mum can be a abstract class.

Comment: Surely i can help you. Can you explain your requirement in detail?

Comment: basically, its a mum survey. There are 3 different types of mums - goingtodeliver, mums with baby one year or less (new), and experienced mums (mums with one year or more kid). Some questions are common to all of them like 'Are u going to put child in daycare'? the question id's are different for these questions. Some questions are'nt like when did you stop breasfeeding, to be mums don't have this question. So, would like to create a solution which avoid copy/paste and also like changing code in three different places (bad code smell). hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah sure. I will help you by posting an example which clearly explains you. If the above answer helps you, please vote or mark correct answer.

Comment: user2549110, please refer my new answer for your second question and vote it, if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for user2549110's second question.

Try creating an abstract class like AbsMumSurvey.cs which should contain the following,

```
public abstract class AbsMumSurvey
{
   public abstract void IsDayCare();

   public abstract void IsEconomicalToEducateChild();

   public int NoOfBabies()
   {
       return 2;

       //This is the sample logic just for understanding. You can write your own logic. 
   }
}
```

Now IsDayCare() and IsEconomicalToEducateChild() are the abstract methods which should be compulsorily overridden in the derived class.

Now in GoingToDeliver.cs, you can do like the following.

```
public class GoingToDeliver : AbsMumSurvey
{
    public override void IsDayCare()
    {
        //Write your logic here.
    }

    public override void IsEconomicalToEducateChild()
    {
        //Write your logic here.
    }
}
```

you may or may not implement NoOfbabaies(). If you also want to implement NoOfBabies(), try the following code.

```
    public new int NoOfBabies()
    {
        return base.NoOfBabies();
    }
```

Same way, you can derive these methods from many classes.

Comment: You can also create `virtual` methods instead of `abstract` and implement common logic in the base class.

Comment: Yes you are right Mr. Jakub. But the user2549110 wants the method to be abstract.

Comment: `user2549110 wants the method to be abstract` - can't see it in the question.

Comment: I've checked the edit history and the requirement of abstract methods was never there.

Comment: Why checking the edit history and all. Just place the mouse cursor on top of edit symbol and check. It shows as "this comment was edited"..Now is this the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32877/discussion-between-jakub-konecki-and-shafiq-abbas)

Answer (score 0):

I would extract out a common method for the following:

```
var oneA = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q49d"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };

            var oneB = from a in answers
                       where a.Questionid == "Q65d"
                       select new QuestionInfo { questionId = a.Questionid, userId = a.UserId };
```

And pass in the QuestionIds as parameters instead of hard coding them in the code. This new method can then be called from both of your existing methods and avoid duplicated code